# Is it possible to rename svn tag

Tags: svn, tags, rename

Is it possible to rename a tag in subversion?

Whenever I release a production version of the application, I tag the revision with the corresponding number, e.g, when version `1.0.0` was released, a corresponding tag was created:

```
svn copy https://svn.mydomain.com/project/trunk https://svn.mydomain.com/project/tags/v_1.0.0
```

In this same manner, I just checked in the code for version `1.0.3` of the application and create the corresponding tag.  However I noticed that when `1.0.2` was released, the tag was created as `v_1.2` instead of `v_1.0.2`.  Is there a way to rename the tag?  At present, I have this:

```
r14 - final changes for version 1.0.2
r15 - tag 1.2 created
r16 - more changes
r17 - more changes
r18 - final changes for 1.0.3
r19 - tag 1.0.3 created
```

I'd like to rename tag `1.2` to `1.0.2`.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can rename **any** part of subtree in Subversion repository.

Tag (any tag) is just directory inside /tags (if you use conventional layout). And rename can be applied to it

`svn mv <REPO>/tags/v_1.2 <REPO>/tags/v_1.0.2`